# Swift 3: Passing Data Forward Doesn't Work/Crashes

Tags: ios, segue, swift3, viewcontroller, sigabrt

Hi so I'm pretty new to swift and I am trying a simple task: pass data between view controllers. I know that this is pretty easy in SWIFT 2 but I can only find a few articles for this using Swift 3.

Here is my simplified code:

```
class logInView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var l2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Get User Input
        let user = username.text
        let pass = password.text
        print(user)
        print(pass)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "logInToInfoSegue"{
            if let destination = segue.destination as? infoView {
                // stuff inside 

            }
        }
    }

}
```

The segue name from the first view to the second is named `logInToInfoSegue`.
The first view controller is named `logInView`.
The second view controller is named `infoView`.
So my questions are:

1. What code do I need to pass the data from the entered text to the next view controller, because the link above doesn't work for me.
2. Why is `if segue.identifier == "logInToInfoSegue"` line of code giving me a Thread 1 SIGABRT error and crashing my app?

Please explain the code if you can answer, I'm still really new to swift but I have moderate experience with other languages.

Comment: Is the variable isDetailingEnabled a computed property with a set method?

Comment: That was my old code sorry there is nothing in there for now... is it important to have stuff inside the if let statement/ what would it do?

Comment: The code is fine, most likely is the instancing of the infoView that's causing the issue, try checking the names in the storyboards, and check if everything is connected nicely.

Comment: I'd set breakpoint in `prepare(for segue:sender:)` and single step through that. The problem can't be that `if` statement, but rather something else in there. But we can't diagnose it based upon the information provided.

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem at hand, but I'd suggest calling your classes `LogInViewController` and `InfoViewController`. A class name should, by convention, alway start with uppercase letter. (Variables start with lowercase letters; classes uppercase letters.) Also a class with `View` in its name would suggest it's a `UIView` subclass, not a `UIViewController` subclass. Generally view controller classes end with `ViewController`, not `View`. Neither of these are related to your current problems, but you'll thank yourself in the long run if you follow established Cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: Having said all of this, this code snippet doesn't quite make sense, though, because you have `submit` method that sets to local variables, prints those values, and discards the results, and your `prepare` method doesn't do anything at all. So nothing is passed to the destination scene. Perhaps you're doing something where you say "stuff inside"?

Comment: I was following a youtube video that said put this inside:     destination.passedData = sender as! String
                print(sender)

Comment: Also in the youtube guide, it showed putting this: performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInToInfoSegue", sender: self) inside the submit button action.

Comment: . I dont think that's the problem, however, I did put destination.passedData = sender as! String print(sender) inside it the if let function and I got a SIGABRT error